# Did "Amityville: The Awakening" ever get released?

Tags: amityville-the-awakening

I watched the trailer of "Amityville: The Awakening" and it said that it was set to release in January of 2015.

However, I cannot find any evidence of this movie being released. I checked [its Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amityville:_The_Awakening) where it says it's to TBD (to be decided/announced).

Anybody knows what's going on with this movie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.shocktillyoudrop.com/news/365877-dimension-films-reshuffling-release-dates-amityville-demonic/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=dimension-films-reshuffling-release-dates-amityville-demonic), this movie and another, Demonic, are still awaiting release dates, and they're not sure why it was pushed back.

> Just when you thought things were set for two upcoming Dimension Films horror releases–the James Wan-presented Demonic, recently set for December 12, and the reboot Amityville: The Awakening, previously set for January 2, 2015–the studio has mysteriously removed both movies from their release schedule without any notice of when they might be rescheduled.
>
> We certainly don’t want to read too much into this decision, since maybe parent company The Weinstein Company has just decided to use their marketing resources elsewhere and plan on releasing them both sometime later in the new year, but right now, both of them are off the release schedule for whatever reason.

As of February of this year, no release date has been set yet.  [Source](https://uk.yahoo.com/movies/delayed-horror-reboot-amityville-the-awakening-112140216929.html)